# How to add label on Distance File - Orange

Tags: cluster-analysis, distance, orange

How to add label to each object/ row in distance file in Orange?

I've tried as the example in this [link](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/widgets/rst/unsupervized/distancefile.html)

```
4
john   0.1
joe    0.5    0.3
jack   0.7    0.9    0.2
jane   0.2    0.8    0.6    0.5
```

but Orange give the following error:

```
Error while reading the file: 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:'john"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example is broken. It should be like this:

```
4 labelled
john   0.1
joe    0.5    0.3
jack   0.7    0.9    0.2
jane   0.2    0.8    0.6    0.5
```